How can I ensure that my Python logic runs exclusively on the Apache Ray Worker Nodes?
I am using Apache Ray to create a customized cluster for running my logic. However, when I submit my tasks with ray.remote, they are executing on the driver node rather than on the worker nodes I configured during Ray initialization. How can I ensure that my logic runs exclusively on the worker nodes?
import os
os.environ["RAY_PROFILING"] = "1"
os.environ["RAY_task_events_report_interval_ms"] = "0"

import ray
from ray.util.spark import setup_ray_cluster, shutdown_ray_cluster
from ray.util import get_node_ip_address

RAY_LOGS_VOLUME_PATH = "***/temp/apache_ray_logs"
RAY_TIMELINE_VOLUME_PATH = "***/temp/apache_ray_logs/timeline.json"
MAX_WORKER_NODES = 2

try:
  shutdown_ray_cluster()
except:
  pass

try:
  ray.shutdown()
except:
  pass

if not os.path.exists(RAY_LOGS_VOLUME_PATH):
  os.makedirs(RAY_LOGS_VOLUME_PATH)

_, cluster_address = setup_ray_cluster(
  max_worker_nodes = MAX_WORKER_NODES,
  memory_worker_node = 28 * 2**30,
  num_cpus_per_node = 4,
  num_gpus_worker_node = 0,

  collect_log_to_path = RAY_LOGS_VOLUME_PATH
  )

ray.init(
  address = cluster_address,
  ignore_reinit_error = True
  )

ray.timeline(filename=RAY_TIMELINE_VOLUME_PATH)


@ray.remote
def some_function(input):
  print(f"Node used: {get_node_ip_address()}")
  # Some Logic

sources = ["input1", "input2"]
results = ray.get([some_function.remote(x) for x in sources])


what is your expected output?

@RakeshGovindula My Task should be process on Worker Node only as I have configured to have 28GB of memory, but driver node has around 5GB and I am running heavy task. Hence I would like to direct ray to use Worker node than Driver node for the better performance.

Starting your head node with 0 logical CPUs using the command ray start --head --num-cpus=0 instructs the Ray scheduler not to schedule any tasks or actors requiring logical CPU resources on the head node.
This configuration keeps the head node stable by dedicating it only to Ray system processes.
For more information, refer to the following links:

The official documentation https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/scheduling/resources.html#physical-resources-and-logical-resources
Best practices for Kuberay https://github.com/ray-project/kuberay/blob/master/docs/best-practice/worker-head-reconnection.md#best-practice

I have used Ray with this configuration for a long time. See the screenshot below, which shows the head node excluded from task execution:


EDIT: Please see how the mentioned property is utilized with this example: https://github.com/ray-project/kuberay/blob/23b08e0d3d56a1ff95f64ffed20d01028c84a8e8/ray-operator/config/samples/ray-cluster.autoscaler.yaml#L47

I am starting cluster as below
''''
_, cluster_address = setup_ray_cluster(
max_worker_nodes = 8,
memory_worker_node = 10 * 2**30,
num_cpus_per_node = 4,
num_gpus_worker_node = 0
)
ray.init(
address = cluster_address,
ignore_reinit_error = True
)
'''
I dont have option to pass "ray start --head --num-cpus=0"
I am using Azure Databricks Cluster

@Learnings, I am not sure how Ray is deployed in Azure Databricks Cluster, I deploy Ray through Kuberay which requires only this line https://github.com/ray-project/kuberay/blob/23b08e0d3d56a1ff95f64ffed20d01028c84a8e8/ray-operator/config/samples/ray-cluster.autoscaler.yaml#L47 to exclude head node from job scheduling. If the deployment is done by Azure side, I suggest you to contact with them to request this option
